# How to detect a killed connection to Faye client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, faye

I am using Faye with Rails. When a browser client subscribes, we save the channel name to the database and associate it with the subscribed user for unrelated reasons.

I want to be able to delete these `WebsocketChannel` records in the database when the client disconnects. But the primary way the client disconnects is when the browser is closed.

I looked at [Faye Monitoring](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/monitoring.html) and tried to use the `disconnect` event, but it does not fire when the browser is closed. (This makes sense, I think the javascript client has to explicitly disconnect for this event to fire).

What's a good way to manage this?

I'm currently using a timestamp and expiring channels after X minutes, but that is not good enough.

Also, we are using `Net:HTTP` to publish to clients. When a client doesn't exist, this `POST` still returns successful (which I think is a bug).